# при наборе номера телефона , курсор переходит на следующий input и в input-е с номером телефона стейт не меняется. Как сделать?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как сделать можно такое поведение:
при наборе номера телефона , курсор переходит на следующий input и в input-е с номером телефона уже ничего нельзя писать. Значение стейта на onChange не меняется, когда номер телефона полностью написан

Comment: при нажатии на клавишу или просто вписать 10 цифр и больше нельзя?

Comment: просто вписать и нельзя. вот например как у них https://www.tinkoff.ru/cards/debit-cards/tinkoff-black/?internal_source=mainbanner#start
внизу есть форма. там вписываем номер телефона и после сразу курсор на другом инпуте. и если я перейду на инпут с номером телефона и начну что-то набирать на onChange значение в стейте  меняться не будет

Comment: ну я если клацаю на инпут после ввода переходит и можо редактировать

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
    $('input').on('keyup keydown', function(e){
        //Фикс клавиши Backspace
        if(e.keyCode == 8) {
            $(this).attr('full', 'false');
            return;
        }
        //Тут надо вешать атрибуты на инпуты и делать проверку к каждом
        //Сейчас только на номере
        if($(this).val().length >= 12){
           $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, 12));
           $(this).attr('full', 'true');
           $(this).next('input').focus();
            //Нужно, чтобы последний символ не перекинулся на следующий инпут
           return false;
        }else $(this).attr('full', 'false');
    });
    $('input').on('blur', function(){
        if($(this).attr('full') == 'true') $(this).addClass('inHold');
        else $(this).removeClass('inHold');
    });
    $('input').on('focus', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('inHold');
    });
});
```

```css
.inHold{
    background: rgba(50,50,50,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="+7">
<input type="text">
```

Comment: на вопросе стоит тэг reactjs, это не совсем jquery